# Is it possible to reduce the size of the maven distribution

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am currently developing a `go lang` application which will be used to provision a server (written in `Java`) by building a given `pom.xml` file. Since `Java` is required for running the server, the running system is already having `Java` installed but it could or could not have `maven` installed.

So without installing `maven` or setting `M2_HOME` in `$PATH` variable of the running system, the `go` application is written in such a way that it uses a exploded `maven` distribution (which is needed to be packed with the release) for the above provisioning.

Since the `maven` distribution (apache-maven-3.5.2-bin.zip) size is around 9MB the release zip of the application becomes bulky as it is packed with exploded `maven` distribution. If possible is there any way of reducing the size of the `maven` distribution by keeping only the libs which required for performing the `maven` build, so that the release zip will become less bulky.

Comment: First why are you packaging it yourself? Set the JAVA_HOME and that's it...The parts are in the distirbution package are needed? I don't understand the problem...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see the updated question

Comment: `M2_HOME` is not needed. Only the PATH entry. But if you call `mvn` directly `PATH` is not needed neither.Apart from that you didn't answer my question?

Comment: @khmarbaise please pardon me, I updated the questions with the whole user story, please be kind enough to have a look again

Comment: Just to understand you correctly, the exploded maven distribution has a size of approx. 10 MB, and that is the problem? I'm not sure why you would care about 10 MB. What kind of servers do you use?

Comment: Why do you need a Maven to run an Java application? Maven is needed for building an Java application but not for Runtime...furthermore Apart from that really taking care on 10 MiB size on a build server? And to be honest I don't understand your problem..Why do you need a Maven for a Go application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the responses received from the `maven-mailing list`, the `maven` installation/distribution just includes the basic features to perform the core features of a build and additional plugins are downloaded as needed to do specific tasks during the build steps. As they suggests the only way to reduce the size is by removing the `jansi` jar which is used for colour logging.